# Including Icons/Background Images with APK

Tags: android

I'm wanting to include some wallpapers and custom icons with my next application update. What's the best way to go about that in Android? I've been doing some searching but I haven't seen anything satisfactory.

Thanks.

Comment: What I'm trying to do is include images that the user can set as wallpaper on their home screen. I'd love to add a menu entry into Wallpapers, but I don't know how feasible that is without creating a custom Launcher. Would the best way just include the images in the APK then save them to SD when the app is installed for the first time?

Answer (score 1):

Just change the icon and the background and update the app. Or do you mean something else?

Comment: I mean, as like an image pack. So the user can long press the homescreen and they'll see an option I put in there for wallpapers. Or, if that requires creating a custom launcher, just a way to include the images so they'll show up in the home screen wallpaper list.

Comment: ah.. as like an image bundle or like that. Yes this should be possible. You just have to extract the Drawables in a certain folder. But as for now I dont know how to create an additional optionsmenu point sorry.

Answer (score 0):

I know if your app moves/copies the files to the user's SD card then the media scanner should pick it up and include in the Gallery app. Which can then be used as a wallpaper. But as for using them directly from your app, I'm not sure.

Might be good to not include them in the app directly, but allow the user to choose to download them from within your app (if you have a server or external site you can host them on). That would keep the size of your app small, and allow you to download them directly to the user's SD card.